# Most frequent value with group by two columns mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a table (test) with two columns (name varchar(5), cnt int)

Table Name: `test`

```
+--------+-------------+
| column |    type     |
+--------+-------------+
| name   | varchar (5) |
| cnt    | int         |
+--------+-------------+
```

and have values

```
+------+-----+
| name | cnt |
+------+-----+
| A    |   1 |
| A    |   1 |
| A    |   1 |
| A    |   2 |
| B    |   1 |
| B    |   2 |
+------+-----+
```

I like to get result of most frequent count with unique name

So the expected result will be

```
+------+------+-------+
| name | cnt  | count |
+------+------+-------+
| A    |    1 |     3 |
| B    |    1 |     1 |
+------+------+-------+
```

As A has two 1 and one 2 and B has one 1 and one 2

I tried the query like

```sql
select distinct name, cnt, COUNT(cnt) as count
from test
group by cnt, name
order by count desc
```

But the result I am getting

```
+------+------+-------+
| name | cnt  | count |
+------+------+-------+
| A    |    1 |     3 |
| A    |    2 |     1 |
| B    |    1 |     1 |
| B    |    2 |     1 |
+------+------+-------+
```

here is the sql fiddle **[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9d85c/21)**

Comment: A has 3 one and 1 two? And if B has one 1 and one 2 why show only the 1 count?

Comment: You may need dense rank what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Sorry I add one row extra while posting for this question. I adjusted answer @P.Salmon

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: @Atiq Consider upgrading to MySQL 8+, which has features which can make your life a lot easier.  Writing an answer to your question without window functions will be ugly, and a real pain.

Comment: For B, 1 & 2 seem equally frequent

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen currently upgrading is not an option :(

Answer (score 2):

A correlated query with `LIMIT` could be used to find the most occurring value:

```
SELECT name, cnt, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM t
WHERE cnt = (
    SELECT cnt
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE name = t.name
    GROUP BY cnt
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY name, cnt
```

Comment: There is a subtle potential problem with your correlated limit subquery.  It does currently appear to pick the lower value of `cnt` with the max count, for each `name` group in the event of a tie (e.g. `B`).  But there is no guarantee of this, at least not based just on your SQL.  I can think of other databases (e.g. Postgres) where your query could produce the incorrect result.

Comment: OP did not mention what happens if the counts tie. The RDBMS is free to choose any. But it is easy to break the tie by explicitly modifying the order by e.g. `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, cnt -- prefer smaller value`.

Comment: Good save +1.  I like your answer more than my MySQL 5 answer.  But the `ROW_NUMBER` approach is probably the simplest, and easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this using window functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name, cnt, COUNT(*) AS count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, cnt) rn
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name, cnt
)

SELECT name, cnt, count
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

Here is my attempt at a pre-MySQL 8+ solution:

```
SELECT t1.name, MIN(t1.cnt), MAX(t1.count)
FROM
(
    SELECT name, cnt, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name, cnt
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, MAX(count) AS max_count
    FROM
    (
        SELECT name, cnt, COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY name, cnt
    ) t
    GROUP BY name
) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.count = t2.max_count
GROUP BY
    t1.name;
```

### Demo

The difficulty here is that we first have to aggregate by both `name` and `cnt`, to find the max counts for each group.  Then, this has to be subqueried to find the group for each `name` having the highest count.  Finally, another aggregation is required to find the `name` group with the *lowest* `cnt` value, in the case that a given `name` happens to have two sub groups with the same count (e.g. `B`).

Comment: @fa06 Your comment does not belong here...at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, opps sorry

Comment: @Atiq I have given you an option which should work on your version of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to report all entries in the event of a draw

```
select name,cnt,obs
from
(
select s.name,s.cnt,obs ,
    if(s.name <>@pname, @rn:=1,if(s.obs<>@pobs,@rn:=@rn+1,@rn:=@rn)) denserank,
    @pname:=s.name,
    @pobs:=s.obs
from
(
select t.name, t.cnt,count(*) obs
from t
group by t.name,t.cnt
) s
) t
where denserank = 1;

+------+------+-----+
| name | cnt  | obs |
+------+------+-----+
| A    |    1 |   3 |
| B    |    1 |   1 |
| B    |    2 |   1 |
+------+------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below using corelated subquery

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS name, 1 AS cnt UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 2
),
cte2 as (
select  name, cnt, COUNT(*) as cn
from yourTable 
group by cnt, name
) select t1.* from cte2 t1 where t1.cn=( select max(cn) from cte2 t2 
                                        where t2.name=t1.name
                                     )

name    cnt     cn
A        1      3
B        1      1
B        2      1
```

As for B both frequency is same that's why both will come on output, You can change this cte to subquery version

Comment: Your current output does not match what the OP is expecting.  The OP expects one record for each `name`, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

this work:

```
  SELECT a.name,a.cnt,max(a.count) AS count FROM (
         SELECT distinct name, cnt, COUNT(cnt) as count
         FROM test
         GROUP BY name,cnt
 ) a
 GROUP BY a.name
 ORDER BY a.count DESC
```

Comment: This query is invalid, because you are using `GROUP BY` in the outer query on the `name`, but then are selecting non aggregate columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  did you test it or not?

Comment: [It won't even run](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3278a9e1b89b4aaf647a159f0d264457) on certain versions of MySQL.  Hence, you should not be putting this forth as a recommendation to other people.

Answer (score 0):

I did something myself But not sure its efficient to do. As My table might have lots of entry.

```
select * from 
(select distinct name, cnt, COUNT(cnt) as count
from test
group by cnt, name
order by count desc) A
group by name
```